# Why is Kathryn's dog's name Ajax?

Tags: character, once-upon-a-time

In Once Upon a Time, every character seems to have a significant name in Storybrooke, they [complement their real names](http://www.fanpop.com/clubs/once-upon-a-time/articles/131114/title/significance-real-world-character-names). Even Pongo is a reference to 101 Dalmatians, but why is Kathryn's dog's name Ajax?

This seems a bit out of the box or is it some other reference I am missing?

Comment: Since Disney owns Marvel, the Dogs name is really Francis.

Comment: @cde - I would up vote that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Kathryn's Enchanted Forest counterpart, Abigail, is the daughter of King Midas. Although there is no character named Ajax in the King Midas myth (which is honestly pretty low on detail), Ajax was a character from another Greek myth. In the Iliad, Ajax was a particularly strong and courageous fighter. So, pretty good name for Greek character's dog!